# Pandas rolling_max with variable window size specified in a df column

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to calculate a rolling_max of a pandas column, where the window size varies and is a difference between current row index and a row where a certain condition was met.

So, as an example, I have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0],
                   'b': [5,4,3,6,1,2,3,4,2,1,7,8]})
```

I want a rolling_max of df.b since df.a == 1 the previous time. I.e. I want to get this:

```
     a   b   rm
 0   0   5   NaN  <- no previous a==1
 1   1   4   4    <- a==1
 2   0   3   4
 3   0   6   6
 4   0   1   6
 5   1   2   2    <- a==1
 6   0   3   3
 7   0   4   4
 8   0   2   4
 9   0   1   4
10   1   7   7    <- a==1
11   0   8   8
```

My df has an integer index without gaps, so I tried to do this:

```
df['last_a'] = np.where(df.a == 1, df.index, np.nan)
df['last_a'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
df['rm'] = pd.rolling_max(df['b'], window = df.index - df['last_a'] + 1)
```

but I'm getting a TypeError: an integer is required.

This is a part of a long script operating on quite a big data frame, so I need the fastest solution possible. I have successfully tried to do this with a loop instead of rolling_max, but it's very slow. Could you please help?

Just for reference. The ugly and long loop that I have now, and which, regardless its ugliness, seems to be quite fast on my data frame (50,000 x 25 for a test), is as follows:

```
df['rm2'] = df.b
df['rm1'] = np.where( (df['a'] == 1) | (df['rm2'].diff() > 0), df['rm2'], np.nan)
df['rm1'].fillna(method = 'ffill', inplace = True)
df['Dif'] = (df['rm1'] - df['rm2']).abs()
while df['Dif'].sum() != 0:
    df['rm2'] = df['rm1']
    df['rm1'] = np.where( (df['a'] == 1) | (df['rm2'].diff() > 0), df['rm2'], np.nan) 
    df['rm1'].fillna(method = 'ffill', inplace = True)
    df['Dif'] = (df['rm1'] - df['rm2']).abs()
```

Comment: Big data frame? Fastest solution? Conditionally aggregate? All classic needs of an SQL engine solution, leaving your RAM to rest a bit. Does data derive from an RDMS?

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion Parfait! Probably, I'll follow it, since my current process is painstakingly slow. I was not expecting it to be that slow, and I was also hoping to learn some Python in the process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would create an index and `groupby` this index to use `cummax`:

```
import numpy as np

df['index'] = df['a'].cumsum()
df['rm']    = df.groupby('index')['b'].cummax()

df.loc[df['index']==0, 'rm'] = np.nan

In [104]: df
Out[104]:
    a  b  index  rm
0   0  5      0 NaN
1   1  4      1   4
2   0  3      1   4
3   0  6      1   6
4   0  1      1   6
5   1  2      2   2
6   0  3      2   3
7   0  4      2   4
8   0  2      2   4
9   0  1      2   4
10  1  7      3   7
11  0  8      3   8
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Colonel Beauvel! Elegant and works perfectly! At the same time, surprisingly, my lengthy and ugly loop solution works much much faster on a big data frame (I've tested on 50,000 x 25). 17.5ms for my ugly loop vs 2.68s for your cute one. Probably, as Parfait suggested, I'd really rather move to SQL with such tasks. 
Just for your reference, I'll update my initial post with a loop I've got - maybe there's still something to squeeze from it.
Unfortunately, I can't +1 you yet, which I'll do if and when I get higher reputation.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Interesting to see the groupby is quite slow. I am thinking about a faster solution with itertools, will try to post it this wk. For the +1 no worries, you can do it later!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, anytime you require restructuring data that involves relationships between columns and tables, consider an SQL solution using a Relational Database Management System (RDMS). And do so especially if your data derives from a database. Leave Pandas for data analysis. Of course, if you are storing large data not in a database, then that's whole another issue!

Python comes equipped with a built-in library for [SQLite](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html), the popular free, open-source file-level database. Additionally, Python libraries for MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, Oracle, and other RDMSs are available for install. You can integrate each connection seamlessly into [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html). Below are three equivalent versions of queries to achieve your conditional group max. Each assumes you maintain an autonumber primary key index, `ID`, in your source table, named here as `RollingMax`.

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import pandas as pd

con = lite.connect('C:\\Path\\SQLite\\DB.db')

# SQL WITH DERIVED TABLES
sql = """SELECT a, b,
               (SELECT Max(dtbl2.B) 
               FROM 
                   (SELECT t1.ID, t1.a, t1.b,
                          (SELECT Count(*) FROM RollingMax t2 
                           WHERE t1.ID >= t2.ID AND t2.A > 0) As GrpA
                    FROM RollingMax t1) dtbl2
               WHERE dtbl1.ID >= dtbl2.ID 
               AND dtbl1.GrpA = dtbl2.GrpA) As rm

         FROM 
         (
              SELECT t1.ID, t1.a, t1.b,
                     (SELECT Count(*) FROM RollingMax t2 
              WHERE t1.ID >= t2.ID AND t2.A > 0) As GrpA
              FROM RollingMax t1
         ) As dtbl1;"""

# SQL USING CTE WINDOW FUNCTION (AVAILABLE AS OF VERSION 3.8.3)
sql = """WITH grp (ID, a, b, GrpA)
         AS  (
              SELECT t1.ID, t1.a, t1.b,
                    (SELECT Count(*) FROM RollingMax t2 
                     WHERE t1.ID >= t2.ID AND t2.A > 0) As GrpA
              FROM RollingMax t1
             )
         SELECT a, b,
               (SELECT Max(dtbl2.B) 
                FROM grp AS dtbl2
                WHERE dtbl1.ID >= dtbl2.ID 
                AND dtbl1.GrpA = dtbl2.GrpA) As rm
         FROM grp AS dtbl1;"""

# SQL USING SAVED VIEW
'''To be saved inside database'''
saved_view = """SELECT t1.ID, t1.a, t1.b,
                  (SELECT Count(*) FROM RollingMax t2 
                   WHERE t1.ID >= t2.ID AND t2.A > 0) As GrpA
                FROM RollingMax t1;"""

sql = """SELECT a, b,
             (SELECT Max(dtbl2.B) 
              FROM saved_view AS dtbl2
              WHERE dtbl1.ID >= dtbl2.ID 
              AND dtbl1.GrpA = dtbl2.GrpA) As rm
         FROM saved_view As dtbl1;"""

df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
```

**OUTPUT**  *(only challenge here is the first grouping without preceding a==1)*

```
a   b   rm
0   5   5
1   4   4
0   3   4
0   6   6
0   1   6
1   2   2
0   3   3
0   4   4
0   2   4
0   1   4
1   7   7
0   8   8
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Parfait. Currently my data is a CSV table downloaded through API. Unfortunately the server doesn't allow direct SQL connection. So I'll have to think about setting up a local MySQL server and translating the whole process from Python to SQL before trying your suggestions.

Comment: Consider [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/index.html), a lightweight file level RDMS but still powerful (each file size limit - [140 terabytes](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)). MySQL is a enterprise level server level RDMS and may require some infrastructure to set up and run. But then I do run it off my laptop! Good luck!